# Insert and Load Record using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to learn jQuery and Ajax and have found a great tutorial to insert and load records.

[The tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/insert-and-load-record-using-jquery-and.html)

But I have not managed to make it load records when I refresh the page. The comments that I have added are stored on the database but they are not displayed when I refresh the page.

Anyway I can make display the inserted records?

Comment: You need to show us the code you wrote, so we can help. What server side language are you using? Are you using firebug, or chrome developer tools to debug the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three way to set record after insert.

1. after insert record, **return inserted record and append in list.**
2. after insert record, **just get value text box and add in list.**
3. after insert record, **list return and add to list or div.**